# Unknown Format Conversion Exception?

Tags: java, printf

I have the following code. During run time, an exception is generated whenever this method executes generating an `UnknownFormatConversionException`. I am trying to display the values to 2 decimal places.

```
public void totalPrice(Vector <Stock> temp){
    if(!out){
        cst = temp.elementAt(l).getCost();
        cost = Double.parseDouble(cst);
        tax = ((cost * q) * 2)/100;
        price = (cost * q) + tax;
        System.out.printf ("Product Cost: € %.2f\n", (cost * q));
        System.out.printf ("Tax Total (2% rate): € %.2f\n", tax);
        System.out.printf ("Net Cost: € %.2f\n", price); 
        System.out.println ("============================================="); 
        System.out.println (); 
    }
}
```

Comment: at which row you're getting the exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `%%` when you want to use a `%` literal. Also, while not causing your error, you will want to use `%n` not `\n`.

i.e.,

```
System.out.printf ("Tax Total (2%% rate): € %.2f%n", tax);
```

For more on the details, you will want to check out the [Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Also, if you want to display currency, you might be better off using a `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale someLocale)`.